# Call a Split View from another view

Tags: ios, ipad

I am a beginner in iOS programming..

I have created two iPad based projects, where one is a view based application and other one is a split view based application.

Now, I want to integrate the splitview application in to my first project.

I have read in Apple's documentation that a split view needs to be in root view.

How can integrate the split view such that my home screen (from my first project) is shown first, and then on tapping a button, opens the split view..?

Thanks for helping me here..

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565054/ipad-split-view-call-load-from-another-view

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use UITabBarController...

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation, if you want to use split view it must be a SplitView based application. And Split view must be the root view controller.

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split-view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html

Answer (score -1):

You have read it so you know you can't do it using Apple's UISplitViewController. I suggest you check out [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) or [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController). It provides additional customization as well.

Comment: Hi Viraj, I have tried these apps.. But my requirement is to display exactly as the Apple's split view shows up..

Comment: Please check out the app Icon Brickell app [link](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/icon-brickell/id397604696?mt=8)