# How to display UISplitViewcontroller on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is there any way to show the `UISplitViewController` on button click ?

Comment: how many oration support in u r application

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565054/ipad-split-view-call-load-from-another-view

Comment: Please [refere this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) i hope this will help you.

Comment: Check out **[this link](http://geekios.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/how-to-add-uisplitviewcontroller-into-an-ipad-application-through-programmatically/)** for programmatically adding UISplitViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code..

```
@interface ...

-(IBAction)Btn_OpenSplitView:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ...

-(IBAction)Btn_OpenSplitView:(id)sender { 
    UIViewController* secondVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentView"
                                                                    bundle:nil];

    UIViewController* firstVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView"
                                                                   bundle:nil
                                                withContentViewController:secondVC];

    UISplitViewController* splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC, secondVC, nil];

    [self addSubview:splitVC.view];   
}

@end
```